# Meteor hitting Poisson process question

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process

Kate is monitoring her Traffic. She estimates that it is hit by about one car per week. You may assume that the times at which car hit the another car are described by a Poisson process.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't break iff it's hit by no meteors, or by one non-giant meteors or by two non-giant meteors:
$$\Pr(N(2)=0)+.9\Pr(N(2)=1)+.81\Pr(N(2)=2)$$
so the probability that it breaks is $1$ minus the above.